# Remove index.php from a Laravel deployed project

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-6

I´m currently working with Laravel 6 and I'm trying to deploy my project in Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server. My welcome page it works, but when I try to log in, it shows the message:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

But when I try my log in using *index.php/login* I can log in and routing works good, but without CSS, my `.htacces` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/apps/hris/imiforms

    # Redirect trailing slashes if not a folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My *.conf* file in Apache looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/apps/hris/imiforms/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I have enabled my rewrite mode in Apache. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you set the server directory of your Apache config to your Laravel public folder?

Comment: yes, I did found my answer in another Forum, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .htaccess file so that it contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Source: *[How to Remove “public/index.php” from URL in Laravel](https://tecadmin.net/remove-public-index-php-laravel/)*